# dynamically update active tab in accordion via class

Tags: php, jquery, html, session, accordion

I have a accordion tab system, I have two stats applied `active` and `checked`.

I also have a php session present and depending on that session I hide or show some tabs.

*here is my accordion tab with active and checked state*

**my accordion**

```
<label for='product-47-47' class="first active">
                    <input type='checkbox' style="float: left" class='regular-checkbox big-checkbox multicheck'
                           data-paysys="" checked/>

                    <div class="accord-text">
                        <strong>hello world:</strong></br><em>£00.00 for 1 year's access</em>
                    </div>
                </label>
```

*my php session switch statement to hide tabs depending on session*

**php session switch**

```
<?php
            switch ($_SESSION['my_session_data']) {
                case "first":
                    ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .first,.second{
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                    break;
case "second":
                    ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .second,.third {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                    break;
               case "third":
                    ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .first,.third {
                            display: none !important;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                    break;
            default:
                        }
```

I also need to change the check and active state depending on the case

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What's not working?

Comment: so I want to set the active class and checked in the switch statment

Comment: I would think that you'd set the class styles in your CSS and then change the class names on the tabs based on the Session variables. It's still not clear what is not working.

Comment: ok, i would like to set the current active or checked in my switch rather than the tab

Comment: Ok, would need to see more of your example code. It's not clear what you need to change.

Comment: no problem will update this morning